# How to set process.env.PORT on Stencil-JS app

Tags: stencils, stencil-compiler

Does anyone know the proper way to edit the `process.env.PORT` property in a StencilJS app?

Comment: You really need to expand this question - perhaps tell us what outcome you're trying to achieve? This question right now doesn't make much sense. `process.env.PORT` is a back-end feature of node.js, whereas stenciljs builds front-end components...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rollup-plugin-replace` like that: 
In `stencil.config.js`:

```
import replace from 'rollup-plugin-replace';
...
plugins: [
  replace({
    'PROD_URL': process.env.PROD_URL || 'http://localhost:8080',
    'DEV_URL': process.env.DEV_URL || 'http://localhost:7070',
  }),
  ...
]
```

After that in your application you could use `'PROD_URL'` and that string would be replace to your process.env variable.